# R function for Fizzbuzz and Fibonacci number

Tags: r

i am tasked with the following two questions, however for some reason my codes dont work.

Problem 1
Write a function (named FizzBuzz_function) that takes a number from the user (named n) and prints the numbers from 1 to n. However, for multiples of three print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print “FizzBuzz”.

Problem 2
Write a function that takes a number from the user (named n) and returns nth Fibonacci number.
Please check your function: When n is 20, the Fibonacci number (F20) is 6765 (I assume F1=1, F2=1).

Here are my answers but I am not getting any outputs

1.

```
n <- readline(prompt="Enter your number: ")

# define the function
fizz_buzz <-  FizzBuzz_function(n){
  if(n%%3 == 0 & n%%5 == 0) {
    print('FizzBuzz')
  }
  else if(n%%3 == 0) {
    print('Fizz')
  }
  else if (n%%5 == 0){
    print('Buzz')
  }
  else {
    print(n)
  }
  
}
```

2. n <- readline(prompt="Enter your number: ")

   vast=function(n){
   vast=vector()
   vast[1]=1
   vast[2]=1
   for(i in 3:n){vast[i]=vast[i-1]+vast[i-2]}
   return(vast)
   }

Comment: `readline` returns character so make sure n is an integer by coercing it into integer if necessary. Putting `n=as.integer(n)` on the first line will do.

Comment: Btw, you should do your homework without help.